# Printing out MongoDB Documents in JSON Format

Tags: json, swift, mongodb, mongokitten

I am retrieving documents from my mongoDB database, but I need to print it out in JSON format. I store all of the relevant information in an array as the MongoKitten documentation suggests. I want to print out the entire contents of each element in the array, which is remember a document from MongoDB. My code is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import MongoKitten

let myDatabase = try MongoKitten.Database("mongodb://taylor:starwars1@ds129374.mlab.com:29374/taylorswiftengine")
let myCollection = myDatabase["my_collection"]


Request.addHandler(forMethod: "GET", withRoute: "/:resource/:id1")
{  


 (routeParams:RouteParams) in

     let myTopics = try! myCollection.find("topic" == "\(routeParams["id1"]!)")

     let allTopics = Array(myTopics)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoKitten comes with an Extended JSON module, which you can import:

```
import ExtendedJSON
```

You can convert an array of documents (`[Document]`) to Extended JSON using `makeExtendedJSON()`:

`myArrayOfDocuments.makeExtendedJSON()`

This returns a `Cheetah.Value`. Cheetah is OpenKittens JSON library. To get a JSON String, you can use the `serializedString()` method on `Cheetah.Value`.

---

To sum things up, use this to convert your array of BSON Documents to a JSON String:

```
myArrayOfDocuments.makeExtendedJSON().serializedString()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your myTopics object a dictionary you could convert it to json like this:

```
let dict = ["key1": "B", "key2": "A", "key3": "C"]
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Otherwise you could manually convert the myTopics object to a `[String:String]` dictionary and than convert it to json like above but I'm not sure if thats the way to handle with mongodb objects.

Comment: My data looks like this : `[{"_id":"A3D813E8-B16E-4D55-BF94-101B3D0BD6EF","message":"I love Charzard","email":"taylor.mail@email.com","topic":"pokemon"}, {"_id":"D6926E07-7797-41DC-849B-3854543931E0","message":"I love eggs","email":"jobr.mail@email.com","topic":"pokemon"}, {"_id":"0EF27D36-58B3-4AB8-917C-F9955BA75120","message":"I love Pikachu","email":"jobr.mail@email.com","topic":"pokemon"}, {"_id":"6DB65277-E806-43C1-997D-69A21A0E3B4F","message":"I love Gastly","email":"jobr.mail@email.com","topic":"pokemon"}]`